# Angular material md-chips with md-autocomplete: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I tried wrapping mat-chips and mat-autocomplete into an ControlValueAccesor but I get the following errors:

```
InfoEditorComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
    at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.js:2701)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2580)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6318)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6969)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6892)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24499)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067)

KeywordsEditorComponent.html:11 ERROR Error: Cannot find form control at index 2
    at FormArray._throwIfControlMissing (forms.js:4916)
    at forms.js:4711
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormArray.setValue (forms.js:4705)
    at updateControl (forms.js:2691)
    at KeywordsEditorComponent.onChange (forms.js:2663)
    at KeywordsEditorComponent.createKeyword (keywords-editor.component.ts:88)
    at KeywordsEditorComponent.add (keywords-editor.component.ts:50)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (KeywordsEditorComponent.html:19)
    at handleEvent (core.js:34789)
```

This is the wrapper that is essentialy coppied from: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input

```js
import { COMMA, ENTER } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, forwardRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatChipInputEvent } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export const KEYWORDS_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => KeywordsEditorComponent),
  multi: true,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-keywords-editor',
  template: `<mat-form-field class="chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Keywords">
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let keyword of keywords"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(keyword)">
      {{keyword}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New keywords..."
      #keywordInput
      [formControl]="keywordCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let keyword of filteredKeywords | async" [value]="keyword">
      {{keyword}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>`,
  styleUrls: ['./keywords-editor.component.sass'],
  providers: [KEYWORDS_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class KeywordsEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  keywordCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredKeywords: Observable<string[]>;
  keywords: string[] = ['Lemon'];
  allKeywords: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
  onChange;

  @ViewChild('keywordInput', {static: false}) keywordInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('auto', {static: false}) matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor() {
    this.filteredKeywords = this.keywordCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((keyword: string | null) => keyword ? this._filter(keyword) : this.allKeywords.slice()));
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    // Add keyword only when MatAutocomplete is not open
    // To make sure this does not conflict with OptionSelected Event
    if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      // Add our keyword
      this.createKeyword(value);

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }

      this.keywordCtrl.setValue(null);
    }
  }

  remove(keyword: string): void {
    const index = this.keywords.indexOf(keyword);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.keywords.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.createKeyword(event.option.viewValue);
    this.keywordInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.keywordCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allKeywords.filter(keyword => keyword.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  createKeyword(keyword: string) {
    if (!keyword) {
      return;
    }
    let key = keyword.trim()
    if (key !== '' && this.keywords.indexOf(keyword) === -1) {
      this.keywords.push(keyword)
      this.onChange(this.keywords)
    }
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.keywords = obj;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

}
```

Parent form that uses chips with autocomplete:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-editor',
  templateUrl: `<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<app-keywords-editor formControlName="keywords"></app-keywords-editor>
</form>`,
  styleUrls: ['./info-editor.component.sass']
})
export class InfoEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      keywords: this.fb.array(['a','b'])
  })

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder) { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should replace

```
 formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      keywords: this.fb.array(['a','b'])
  })
```

with

```
 formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      keywords: ['a','b']
  })
```

keywords is already a value that should be passed to controll and not an array of controlls